# What is the use of "IsTabStop" Property for a control in xaml?

Tags: .net, windows-8

In MSDN I saw this.But I can't Understand ,Can anyone Explain me Clearly what is the use.

`Gets or sets a value that indicates whether a control is included in tab navigation.`

Comment: Usually indicates whether the control is able to be focused by the user pressing the tab key.  If you have 10 controls and 3 of them are set to be used as tab stops, then the tab key will scroll focus between only those three fields.

Comment: Please note that a control that has IsTabStop-false can still receive focus. IsTabStop is in no way a means to protect a form field from user interaction. It is only meant as a convenience.

Answer (score 9):

Tabbing through a form is ordered based on an explicit TabIndex setting or an implicit TabIndex based on the Page hierarchy. This way you can make sure data entry is fluid - like the user can <kbd>Tab</kbd> from City to State to Zip and NOT from Zip to City to State.

TabIndex is completely meant to make the usability of data entry fields more friendly. In many ways TabIndex helps drive the workflow of your form without explicitly telling the end user. It's very nice but can be very tedious on large forms. Many developers don't bother. They suck. IMHO

IsTabStop is a kind of on off for the <kbd>Tab</kbd> functionality. When set to true (the default) the user will continue to <kbd>Tab</kbd> through your form like normal. When set to false the user will <kbd>Tab</kbd> through your form, but that control will be skipped.

It is important to note that removing a control from the Tab order is only a convenience and in no way protects the control from manually being entered through a mouse's click or a finger's tap.

In a way IsHitTarget is like IsTabStop. But that's for another question ;)

Answer (score 4):

Does what it says on the tin

If you had say three edit boxes and the middle one was display only, you could set tabstop to false on it then Tab from the first would jump to the third. Given the tab order was correct of course.